# Django abstract model migration with south gives error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I have the following model:

```
class MemberCategory(BaseModel):

    """
    Contains Predfined Category Types
    """
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The base model looks like the following:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    """
    An abstract base class model that provides self-managed "created" and
    "modified" multi tenant fields.
    """
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now I go and add a field `org` in my MemberCategory, so that the new model looks like the following:

```
class MemberCategory(BaseModel):

    """
    Contains Predfined Category Types
    """
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    orgs = models.ForeignKey(Org, null=True, blank=True)
```

After this I do - `python manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --auto` No errors, everything fine.

And then I do `python manage.py migrate <app_name>` which throws the following error -

```
KeyError: u'creation_date'
```

Any reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: Just to be sure. Did you do python manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --initial the first time? The --auto option only works when the table already exists in your db.

Comment: Any chance you could drop the last two migrations in a pastebin?